# XkbOptions not working system-wide in NixOS

Tags: gnome, keyboard, nixos

I just migrated from `Arch Linux` to `NixOS`. I configured the system to install `GNOME`. Additionally, I spotted a setting where I can set `XkbOptions` within `services.xserver`:

```bash
// /etc/nixos/configuration.nix
...
services = {
  xserver = {
    desktopManager.gnome.enable = true;
    displayManager.gdm.enable = true;
    enable = true;
    excludePackages = with pkgs; [ xterm ];
    layout = "us";
    xkbVariant = "";
    xkbOptions = "numpad:microsoft"; # ...err, not fully working
  };
};
...
```

I'm under the assumption that setting `XkbOptions` should yield the same results than setting `Num Lock on: ...` under `Compatibility options` in `GNOME Tweaks`:

[image]

...but it's not quite working system-wide. For instance, `Text Editor` and some other applications aren't working working correctly. Moreover, I can verify that setting this in `GNOME Tweaks` (with and without setting `XkbOptions`) will make all applications I've tested work correctly, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong in the `NixOS` configuration file, or if it's some bug with `xkbOptions`.

I would like, if possible, to configure this in `NixOS` declaratively. Any clues of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any `~/.X*` files which may be overriding your system settings?

Comment: Not currently. Usually I don't have any `X.org` related files in home; probably because I always use the option to start a `Wayland` session in `GNOME` — the default one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think somehow I got into a state where this wasn't set properly because I was configuring the system while trying `GNOME Tweaks`...all at the same time. I've read that `NixOS` wouldn't be able to apply the changes stated in the configuration if the setting (or related settings) is/are already configured.

So I went ahead and checked the current value with `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`. Then I opened up `GNOME Tweaks` and unset the option. Additionally, I also did a reset for `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` via the command-line with: `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` — all of this while still having `NixOS` configured with `xkbOptions = "numpad:microsoft"`.

I restarted the system...and everything seems to be working fine. Moreover, I also see `GNOME Tweaks` now, after the restart, with the option selected. So it appears that this is recognized system-wide indeed.